ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_anything_to_df' from 'streamlit.type_util'
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


from streamlit_gsheets import GSheetsConnection

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JDy9md2VZPz4JbYtRPJLs81_3jUK47nx6GYQjgU8qNY/edit?usp=sharing"

conn = st.experimental_connection("gsheets", type=GSheetsConnection)

data = conn.read(spreadsheet=url, usecols=[0, 1])
st.dataframe(data)

I'm getting the following error:
from streamlit_gsheets.gsheets_connection import GSheetsConnection
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_anything_to_df' from 'streamlit.type_util'

I have reinstalled the required versions of NumPy, Streamlit and pandas.
I have also reinstalled st_gsheets_connection.
I just need it to get the data from the spreadsheet.
Versions:

Python 3.11.4
pandas 2.2.2
NumPy 1.26.2
Streamlit 1.37.0


We need to know the versions of Python and streamlit, atlieast.

@TimRoberts i have edited in the versions which i am using

This is a versioning problem.  In a change from 3 weeks ago, those functions were moved from type_util to dataframe_util.  You can try moving back to a previous version of streamlit, or go file a complaint with the streamlist_gsheets folks which are different.

@TimRoberts i did as you wrote and the problem seems to be resolved. Thanks

@TimRoberts or Atreya It's worth adding this as an answer so that the question doesn't remain "unanswered" and so that current and future users know that that this problem can be easily resolved.
